# Utilizing RPM database checksums

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

I would like write my own verification program, ensuring files downloaded from a yum repo have the same checksum as they came with. This is akin to yum-verify.

On Ubuntu, this is done by gathering the contents of .md5sums files. I believe on RedHat, this information is kept in Berkeley DB files located /var/lib/rpm. Utilizing db_dump on BaseNames, Packages, Sha1header, and Sigmd5, I explored the files and do not think they are self-explanatory.

Basically, how can I verify the checksum of a given file programmatically (no bash scripting utilizing yum-verify)?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See rpm --verify code in lib/verify.c for how to retrieve/verify file digests using C.

Python bindings likely have enough methods to retrieve/verify file digests (but I can't think of any Python app that is widely used that implements rpm file digest verification intelligently)

Comment: This did it. Thanks!